# How to add excludedGroups argument to maven command

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

i have 2 maven profiles in my parent/pom.xml file .

The first profile run only a certain group.

```
<configuration>
<groups>com.XXXXXXX.common.daily.util.UnitTest</groups> 
</configuration>
```

the second profile one run all the tests.

I would like to use an argument on the **maven command** 
in the second profile that will exclude 
this:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                <groups>com.XXXXXX.common.daily.util.UnitTest</groups> 
                   <skipTests>${skipFastTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

i don't want to change the pom.xml for the second profile.

I want to know how to add additional parameter for excludedGroups ?

```
mvn test -P=profile2   ______
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in either surefire or failsafe, add 
    `<excludedGroups>${excluded.tests}</excludedGroups>`
and then define this variable `excluded.tests` to be the interface that is used in @Category to mark which tests to bypass.

finally, when running an excluded tests in command line, override this value.  It seems you are excluding `com.XXXXXX.common.daily.util.UnitTest`. Either define it empty in your profile and override with that; or exclude by default but override with empty.

Comment: Please can you elaborate.

Answer (score 12):

You can exclude a category in the plugin configuration in the pom file.  But if you want to dynamically exclude a given group via the mvn command line, you can do so by using the 'excludedGroups' parameter like so:

```
mvn test -DexcludedGroups=com.group.ExcludedCategory
```

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#excludedGroups